# How to label axes in Mayavi using LaTeX math symbols?

Tags: python, mayavi

I'm importing mayavi in a python script to display some 3D data set, it turns out the following *naive* axes labeling doesn't work

```
from mayavi import mlab
axes =mlab.axes(xlabel='$\alpha$', ylabel='$\beta$', zlabel='$\sigma$')
```

Any ideas? I cannot find the solution from either google or the user manual.

Comment: Does Mayavi definitely support TeX labels?  I can't find any mention of it in the documentation.  In Matplotlib, there is a `usetex` option that I think is off by default - maybe there is something similar?

Answer (score 5):

Mayavi does not support LaTeX symbols sadly.

Comment: Indirectly it does, have a look at @greeeeeeen answer:

https://github.com/MuellerSeb/mlabtex

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a package to enable latex support for mayavi called `mlabtex`:
https://github.com/MuellerSeb/mlabtex

It produces an image rendered with matplotlib and uses this as a texture for a `mlab.surf`. The interface is similar to `mlab.text3d`.

With this, you can do something like that:

```
import os
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt'
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
from mayavi import mlab
from mlabtex import mlabtex

TEXT = (r'Sebastian M\"uller, ' +
        r'$f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty ' +
        r'f^{(n)}(x_0)\cdot\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}$')

tex = mlabtex(0., 0., 0.,
              TEXT,
              color=(0., 0., 0.),
              orientation=(30., 0., 0.),
              dpi=1200)
mlab.axes()
mlab.show()
```

[image: Latex in Mayavi]
To label the axes, you can now place the text there by hand.

Good luck!

Comment: You can install it now with ``pip install mlabtex``.

Answer (score 1):

The thread is a bit old, but the problem is still not resolved. For those, who are still interested in using Latex text in mayavi could have a look at this site:

https://pgi-jcns.fz-juelich.de/portal/pages/latex-mayavi.html

There, a workaround is presented, where a latex document is converted to a png file, which is again imported to mayavi. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

As noted in the answer by @freethebees, LaTeX labels are not supported by Mayavi. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635234/mayavi-3d-object-in-matplotlib-axes3d) as a way of achieving LaTeX labels on a Mayavi scene. You can export the Mayavi scene (without axes) as an image and import into PGFPlots, along with a coordinate transform to place the LaTeX-drawn axes correctly.

Example result:

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Try putting an r in front of each string

```
from mayavi import mlab
axes =mlab.axes(xlabel=r'$\alpha$', ylabel=r'$\beta$', zlabel=r'$\sigma$')
```

Comment: This is explained [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).  Without the `r` prefix, `\a` and `\b` are interpreted as escape sequences.  I don't think this should be necessary for `'$\sigma$'`, as `\s` doesn't appear to be a recognised escape sequence.

Comment: you sure it works? I don't have the resources available to test this, but presumably I think the question is more related to whether mayavi supports TeX at all.

Comment: @Zykx: doesn't work for me. Please provide a complete example.

Comment: @Zykx as already mentioned by the others, this answer is not applicable to Mayavi, please consider reviewing it...